# cqlsh to Cassandra “Unable to connect", in containers, on docker-machine VM

Tags: cassandra, osx-mavericks, cqlsh, docker-machine

We’re attempting to run Cassandra (2.2.0) in a container and cqlsh (5.0.1) in another container on a Mac.  It works on a Linux laptop but fails to connect on a Mac (10.9.5).  Failure on Mac (following worked on Linux) is:

```
# Start Cassandra in a Docker container
docker run --detach --name cassandra1 -p 9042:9042 poklet/cassandra
# Connect to Cassandra using cqlsh
docker run -it --rm --net container:cassandra1 poklet/cassandra cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

docker run -it --rm --net container:cassandra1 poklet/cassandra cqlsh cassandra1
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'cassandra1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('172.17.0.10', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

docker run -it --rm --net container:cassandra1 poklet/cassandra cqlsh 172.17.0.10
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.17.0.10': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('172.17.0.10', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

We wanted to verify whether the problem was specific to cqlsh, or simply a port problem.
Instead of trying to connect cqlsh to cassandra, we used curl to connect to a webserver on the same port (on the mac). We stopped the containers and:

```
# started a container with a webserver on port 9042:
docker run -it --name cassandra1 -p 9042:9042 ubuntu
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9042
# and a container to represent “cqlsh”:
docker run -it --rm --net container:cassandra1 ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and were able to perform the following commands successfully on the “clqsh” container (`curl localhost:9042`, `curl cassandra1:9042`, `curl 172.17.0.9:9042`) to show that its not a port problem.

We think this is a cqlsh specific problem on a docker-machine VM.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have cassandra installed on your local machine.

Example:

> `$ docker-machine ip default`
>
> 192.168.0.10
>
> `$ cqlsh  192.168.0.10`